# SwiftUI GridRow height

Tags: swiftui, grid

Is there a way to have variable `GridRow` heights in a `Grid`?  I am trying to draw a horizontal line between grid rows, and it's taking up the entire height of the common grid row.

See the picture below. I would like the red line to be immediately (1 pixel) below first row and immediately above 2nd row:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Grid {
            GridRow {
                Text("Column 1")
                Text("Column 2")
            }
            GridRow {
                GeometryReader { g in
                    Path { x in
                        x.move(to: .zero)
                        x.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: g.size.width,y: 0))
                    }.stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 1).frame(height: 1)
                }
            }.gridCellColumns(2).gridCellUnsizedAxes(.vertical)
            GridRow {
                Text("Row 1 value 1")
                Text("Row 1 value 2")
            }
            GridRow {
                Text("Row 2 value 1")
                Text("Row 2 value 2")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grid row heights are automatically determined by their contents' height, so you don't actually need to set them explicitly.

The extra space you see here are actually the vertical spacing between rows. The default spacing behaviour is that there should be little space between `Text`s, and more space between `Text` and non-`Text` views.

You can override the default spacing behaviour by passing the `verticalSpacing:` argument.

```
Grid(verticalSpacing: 0) {
    ...
}
```

You can then individually adjust each row's spacing by adding padding, e.g. `.padding(.bottom, 20)`.

Also note that rather than using a `Path`, I'd prefer drawing a very thin `Rectangle`:

```
Rectangle()
    .fill()
    .foregroundColor(.red)
    .frame(height: 1)
```

Or a `Divider` with an `overlay`:

```
Divider()
    .overlay(Color.red)
```

Comment: This worked for me.  But, if you wanted to use a dashed line instead of a solid how would you do it without a Path?

Comment: @andrewz `Rectangle.stroke` takes a `StrokeStyle` so you can probably use that. Either way, the original question isn't really about this. 